TabView tabBar reappears when changing tab in SwiftUI
I am having trouble keeping the tabBar hidden in SwiftUI, example:
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var tabIndex = 0

    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $tabIndex) {
            View1()
                .ignoresSafeArea()
                .toolbar(.hidden, for: .tabBar)
                .tag(0)

            Color.white
                .ignoresSafeArea()
                .toolbar(.hidden, for: .tabBar)
                .tag(1)
        }
        .overlay(alignment: .bottomLeading) {
            Button("Tap") {
                if tabIndex == 0 {
                    tabIndex = 1
                } else {
                    tabIndex = 0
                }
            }
            .padding()
        }
    }
}

struct View1: View {
    let data = Array(0..<20)
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            LazyVStack {
                ForEach(data, id: \.self) { _ in
                    Rectangle()
                        .fill(.red)
                        .frame(width: 100.0, height: 100.0)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

On app launch the tabBar is hidden as expected, changing to the second tab has no problems and is also hidden, however when I change back to the first tab and for all subsequent changes back to the first tab the tabBar shows again. It seems to be related to the ScrollView since if I remove it the problem goes away. Not sure how to keep it hidden when the ScrollView is present. How can I fix this? Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

.toolbar(.hidden, for: .tabBar) is just kind of broken unfortunately. Do you actually need a TabView here? The tab bar is never visible.

I was thinking I could just use a HStack and hide the view not showing. Would that have performance implications versus TabView?

HStack? A ZStack makes more sense, doesn't it? Performance-wise they will be pretty much similar, since in both cases all the tabs are going to be in memory, even if only one tab is shown at a time.

ZStack would work. However seems that this approach would not preserve the scroll view offset between changing screens..

Are you using ifs to determine which view to show? Use .opacity instead.

Opacity works, just means there are double screens in the memory now.

That's what TabView would do too. TabView doesn't deallocate the tabs that are not visible. How else do you think it manages to preserve the scroll offset :)

What you are seeing is the background to the tab bar.
To keep it hidden, add .toolbarBackground(.hidden, for: .tabBar) to the child views of the TabView:
TabView(selection: $tabIndex) {
    View1()
        .ignoresSafeArea()
        .toolbar(.hidden, for: .tabBar)
        .toolbarBackground(.hidden, for: .tabBar) //  ADDED
        .tag(0)

    Color.white
        .ignoresSafeArea()
        .toolbar(.hidden, for: .tabBar)
        .toolbarBackground(.hidden, for: .tabBar) //  ADDED
        .tag(1)
}


The issue remains when something is attached to the bottom of the screen, since even though the tabbar is now truly invisible, it is still being added up the safe area of child views.

@Jeffreyジェフリー Sounds like a candidate for a new question with an MRE to demonstrate the new issue.
